# How to iterate through all the items in a list using Observables

Tags: java-8, observable, rx-java2

I am learning how to use rxjava. As shown in the code below, I have `List<List<Person>>` what i am planning to do is to iterate throught all the lists of `Person`
and to display how many object of type `Person` in each list.

I coded the following:

```
.map(p->p.get(0).getName().map(r->r.toUpperCase()).orElse("NULL_VALUE"))
```

but as you see i always reference the item number 0. how can i reference all the items in the list as if I am using for-loop as folows:

```
for (int i = 0; i< length; i++)
    p.get(i)
```

i hope my question is clear.

thanks in advance

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<List<Person>> observables = Observable.create(e-> {
        for(List<Person> p : Main.getPersons()) {
            e.onNext(p);
        }
        e.onComplete();
    });
     observables
    .map(p->p.get(0).getName().map(r->r.toUpperCase()).orElse("NULL_VALUE"))
    .doOnNext(r->System.out.println("r: " + r))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onNextFromObserver: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

private static <T> Observable<T> toObservable(T s) {
    return Observable.just(s);
}
private static List<List<Person>> getPersons() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Sanna1", 59, "EGY"), new Person(null, 59, "EGY"), new Person("Sanna3", 59, null)),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Mohamed1", 59, "EGY"), new Person(null, 59, "EGY")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Ahmed1", 44, "QTR"), new Person("Ahmed2", 44, "QTR"), new Person(null, null, "QTR")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Fatma", 29, "KSA")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Lobna", 24, "EGY")));
}
}
```

**Person**

```
public class Person {
private String name = null;
private String address = null;
private int age;

private Optional<String> optName= null;
private Optional<Integer> optAge= null;
private Optional<String> optAddress = null;

public Person(String name, Integer age, String address) {
    this.optName = Optional.ofNullable(name);
    this.optAge = Optional.ofNullable(age);
    this.optAddress = Optional.ofNullable(address);
}

public Optional<String> getName() {
    return optName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.optName = Optional.ofNullable(name);
}

public Optional<String> getAddress() {
    return this.optAddress;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.optAddress = Optional.ofNullable(address);
}

public Optional<Integer> getAge() {
    return this.optAge;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.optAge = Optional.ofNullable(age);
}
}
```

**update**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<List<Person>> observables = 
    Observable.fromIterable(Main.getPersons());
    observables
    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .concatMap(list->Observable.fromIterable(list)
            .map(p->p.getName()
                    .map(r->r.toUpperCase()).orElse("NULL_VALUE")))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .blockingSubscribe(new Observer<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onComplete: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onError: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onNext: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onSubscribe: ");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fromIterable`s and `concatMap`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<List<Person>> observables =
        Observable.fromIterable(Main.getPersons());

    observables
    .concatMap(personList -> 
        Observable.fromIterable(personList)
        .map(aPerson -> 
            aPerson.getName()
             .map(name -> name.toUpperCase()).orElse("NULL_VALUE")
        )
    )
    .doOnNext(aName -> System.out.println("aName: " + aName))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .blockingSubscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String item) {
            System.out.println("onNextFromObserver: " + item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thans for the code u posted..but i according to the you posted i dont receive any thing from onNext of the observer..please see the update section in my question.

Comment: Works for me. Did you copy-paste from StackOverflow correctly?

Comment: Yes. I get a bunch of `onNext: ` printed out, after I correct the `Object arg0` to `String arg0` which you didn't copy properly.